# Control user name from oracle database with Ajax in JSP

Tags: java, ajax, oracle, jsp, user-controls

How to control user name from oracle database with Ajax in JSP?

When a user creates an account on my website, I want the input username to be checked against all the current usernames in my database(MySQL) and confirmed if it is available.

Does anyone know any good libraries I could use, or a plug-in for jQuery perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know any good libraries I could use, or a plug-in for
>   jQuery perhaps?

No plugin is available in jquery to call Database. For that you should call servlet using Jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Servlet",
    type: "post",
    data: serializedData
});
```

In case, to check username is available you should not call any jsp file. Because jsp should be only for view data. You should call Servlet where database query will call and return true or false on the base of username available or not.